# Is it possible to build an Android project using ant when checking-in to TFS?

Tags: android, ant, tfs, azure-devops

I currently have an Android project checked into our TFS server, and have recently been working on getting it to build using ant and run Junit tests (also using Robolectric and Mockito).

Building my project works fine using ant locally, but I was hoping to configure TFS to build and run my junit tests when I check-in changes.

I found this, however it doesn't mention anywhere that it could work with an Android project

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d7c8577-54b8-47ce-82a5-8649f579dcb6/view/Discussions/1

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Billy

Answer (score 2):

I have most of it working, however, with that said it does not work 100%. I am going to share what I have done in hopes that you can get it working. The part that does not work is when it goes to move the apk to the Drops directory; I get a UnauthorizedAccessException, so I’m close.

What you have to do in general is check in both Java, Ant, and Android SDK into your project and setup the build to run ant against the Andriod SDK and there version of the SDK you want to build against. To do this you need Java, Ant, and the Android SDK in the project. (Here are the resources that I used to get it working to some degree. The part that does not work is moving the apk to the drops directory and I am not sure where it is going, but the ant build is telling that it is built the app successfully. http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html 
http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-eclipse/)

I also wrote something up that was much more detailed on my blog.

http://slmtechnology.com/mobileboys/?p=194

Answer (score 1):

You will need both the Android and JUnit SDK/libs checked also for it work that way.

Comment: How would I check-in the Android-SDK? Would it be possible to install the SDK on the TFS server?

Comment: I think it would be best to include the Android SDK in your project. That you will only have to update it in one place. But I could shot an email to Brian Harry if you want. He is the PM for TFS.